# ¿Alguien sabe por qué tengo este error? Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, constraints

> Error SQL: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (proyectomontecarlo.contenido_carrito, CONSTRAINT idCarritoContenido_CarritoFK FOREIGN KEY (idCarrito) REFERENCES carrito (idCarrito) ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Estructura de la tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE CARRITO (
idCarrito VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
idCliente VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
idSesion VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
fechaHora DATETIME NOT NULL,
aux INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE CONTENIDO_CARRITO ( 
idContenidoCarrito INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
idCarrito VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
idCliente VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
idSesion VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
idArticulo VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
codigoArticulo VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
codigoAlterno VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
costo DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
unidades INT NOT NULL,
subTotal DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
fechaDeRegistro DATETIME NOT NULL,
aux INT NOT NULL
);
```

El Script que le puse es este:

```
ALTER TABLE contenido_carrito
ADD CONSTRAINT idCarritoContenido_CarritoFK FOREIGN KEY (idCarrito) REFERENCES
carrito(idCarrito)ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Las llaves foráneas ya están agregadas, pero no sé por qué marca el error cuando hago los registros. ¿Alguien sabe la solución?

Comment: Por el error indica que ambas tablas ya tienen datos antes de crear la realacion, pero un id de los de la tabla contenido carrito no corresponde o no se encuentra en la tabla carrito, por lo cual la relacion falla al comprobar que los id puedan ser realcionados

Comment: Cómo estás insertando registros?

Comment: Esto puede ocurrir por lo que ya se ha comentado: hay entre las dos tablas algún dato que quedaría huérfano al no existir en la otra tabla. Y también hay casos en que las restricciones quieren establecerse entre una tabla que está en InnoDB mientras que la otra está en MyIsam, es el caso que ocurre [en esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32248525/5587982) y el fallo proviene de que la tabla en MyIsam no puede manejar restricciones como lo hace InnoDB.

Comment: Hola de nuevo Hermann, existen varios motivos por los que tu consulta falla. El primer es que los datos previos no cumplan la restricción, por lo que no se puede crear ésta, y el otro podría ser el que bien apunta @A.Cedano, que una de las tablas no lo soporte (como las MyISAM). Necesitamos el esquema completo de la tabla. Usa `SHOW CREATE TABLE CONTENIDO_CARRITO` y `SHOW CREATE TABLE CARRITO` para obtenerlo.